# Android using Joda time to calculate diference between dates

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime

I just want to know if is possible to calculate the diference between two dates, using this example code, but when the date format is yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
If the date format is yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ, everything works fine.

```
int days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(today), new DateTime(StartTime1)).getDays();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with "`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`" because that format is supported in [ISODateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeParser%28%29) - which handles any `String` parameters being passed into the `DateTime(Object)` constructor.

You should build a suitable `DateTimeFormatter` for "`yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`" and use that instead, e.g. like so:

```
DateTimeFormatterBuilder b = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
b.append(ISODateTimeFormat.yearMonthDay());
b.appendLiteral(" ");
b.append(ISODateTimeFormat.hourMinuteSecond());
DateTimeFormatter fmt = b.toFormatter();
// fmt can now be used to parse "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" patterns, like so:
System.out.println(fmt.parseDateTime("2010-04-20 20:13:59"));
```

**Edit**: To convert from "`yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`" to "`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`" you can just do like this:

```
String dateTime = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()
        .print(fmt.parseDateTime("2010-04-20 20:13:59"));
```

Not sure what good that will do you compared to having a valid `DateTime` (which is what the output of `fmt.parseDateTime("2010-04-20 20:13:59")` will be).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jens. And if i want to convert the "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" format, to this "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" format ?  I think that in my case, it will be the best thing to do. I have to work with diferent timezones.